# Fetch any user's url by email without loggedin With Facebook Graph Api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried this code.it give me user's url but i need to use 
 facebook graph sdk.

```
<?php
function get_data($url) 
{
$ch = curl_init(); 
$timeout = 30;  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
if(curl_errno($ch)) 
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);  
}
curl_close($ch);    return $data; 
} 
$url='http://www.facebook.com/search.php?init=s:email&q=$email&type=users';
$source = get_data($url);
```

Comment: there is no "graph sdk", there is the "graph api" and some sdks like the "php sdk" or the "javascript sdk". so i assume you mean the php sdk. but why do you NEED to use it? and what did you try so far? what exactly is your question?

Comment: Basically i want to find user name based on email address in all social sites i.e to find user of facebook i need to use facebook api simillarly for all social sites... So far i've tried above code and its working just fine but i want to get user using facebook api so can you help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do right now counts as "scraping", which is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

You MUST use the Graph API in order to get data from Facebook, but there is no possibility to get users by email. You can only search for users by name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#search

You would not be allowed to do anything with the data anyway, because that would be a privacy issue. The proper way to get the email of a user is to authorize him with the `email` permission.